# Fabric8: Fail to execute goal - docker:build

Tags: spring, maven, docker, fabric8

I´m trying to build this project from Spring Guru repository https://github.com/springframeworkguru/spring-boot-docker/tree/docker-multiple-containers

It is a tutorial for Docker and Spring integration. However, I´m getting this error message when building the project with "clean package docker:build"

```
Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.0:build (default-cli) on project spring-boot-docker: Execution default-cli of goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.0:build failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.20.0:build: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: unknown
```

I´ve been running docker on a Winddws 10 Pro and building the Spring project with the latest IntelliJ Ultimate.

Comment: you can use a solution provided in the response here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059403/docker-maven-fabric8-plugin-on-windows-building-image-gives-incompatibility-i

Answer (score 1):

You might be using maven version 3.5.3. 
Please download external maven version 3.5.4 and add in your IDE.

And while running "clean package docker:build" select the above latest added maven . 
It will be there in project's Run As -> Run Configurations -> Maven Runtime

Also In your pom.xml use version 0.26.0 instead of 0.20.0 for docker-maven-plugin.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn´t change the problem.